# repeatable blocks with range in oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, hierarchy, aggregation

Please find the below table. The entire data is within DOCSTART and DOCEND. The data is further enclosed within BACCSTART and BACCEND. This type of block is repeatable. I have to pick up any of ABCD which is also repeatable and TOTAL(occurring once per block) and ACCNAME (occurring once per block) for each block within BACCSTART and BACCEND and form an xml like

```
<BACCSTART>
<TOTAL>100</TOTAL>
<ABCD>abcd</ABCD>
<ACCNAME>name</ACCNAME>
</BACCSTART>
```

for each such block. Presently I am using a for loop, but the performance is not up to the mark. It will have around 200 such blocks for which I have to form the xmls within 15 seconds. Presently the for loop is taking around 53 secs.

```
ROWNUM   NAME     VALUE
 1      DOCSTART  null
 2      BACCSTART null
 3      ABCD      abcd
 4      ABCD      abcd2
 5      PQRS      pqrs
 6      PQRS      pqrs2
 7      TOTAL     100
 8      ACCNAME   name
 9      BACCEND   null
 10     BACCSTART null
 11     ABCD      abcd
 12     ABCD      abcd2
 13     PQRS      pqrs3
 14     PQRS      pqrs4
 15     TOTAL     150
 16     ACCNAME   name
 17     BACCEND   null
 18     DOCEND    null
```

Please help me out with this. If this is possible with a time effective query.

It is oracle 10g.

I have just across a modification in the requirement. The value of ACCNAME is present in another cofig table of around 90 rows. From there I have to pick up three values say value1 for ACCNAME and corresponding value2 and value3 and populate as tags in the xml. If I join that table performance would impact. Please suggest. The config table is like

```
HEADER1      HEADER2        HEADER3        HEADER4 ........
<ACCNAME>    value2          value3
.............
.............
.............
.............
```

The data which I presented above, I get it from a table which contains it as a long. After converting it into clob and using xmltable I am getting the above data. Will it be better to use a global temporary table to insert the data before proceeding. Like

```
insert  into data(row_num,name,value)
select /*+ no_xml_query_rewrite , parallel(x,8) */ rownum rn, substr(extractvalue(x.column_value,'/e'),1,instr(extractvalue(x.column_value,'/e'),' ')-1) name,
 substr(extractvalue(x.column_value,'/e'),instr(extractvalue(x.column_value,'/e'),' ')+1)  value
 from dual,
xmltable('e' passing xmltype('<e><e>' || 
replace(long2clob('select longdata from billedacc order by segment_number'), 
'|'||chr(10), '</e><e>')    ||  '</e></e>').extract('e/e')
                       ) x;
```

Also suggest if there is any better way to handle this.

Comment: Which version of Oracle?  Oracle adds to its XML capability with every major release (and some point releases).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given 9000 data rows (500 * the 18 sample rows you provided above) the following code runs in around a second, which should hit your performance targets:

```
DECLARE

  l_xml_data XMLTYPE;

BEGIN

  <<baccstart_loop>>
  FOR r_baccstart IN (
    -- Initially, get all start/end rows
    WITH delimiters_all_rows AS (
      SELECT d.*
      FROM data d
      WHERE d.name IN ('BACCSTART', 'BACCEND')
    )
    -- Lead over the rows order by row_num to get the start/end pairs 
    -- into a single row
    , delimiters_all_rows_joined AS (
      SELECT 
        dar.row_num baccstart_row_num
      , LEAD(dar.row_num) OVER (ORDER BY row_num) baccend_row_num
      , dar.name
      FROM delimiters_all_rows dar
    )
    -- Eliminate the BACCEND rows as we have their row_num values
    SELECT *
    FROM delimiters_all_rows_joined darj
    WHERE name = 'BACCSTART'
  )
  LOOP

    -- Now get all relevant rows for this data block
    WITH data_rows AS (
      SELECT d.*
      FROM data d  
      WHERE d.row_num > r_baccstart.baccstart_row_num AND d.row_num < r_baccstart.baccend_row_num
      AND (
        d.name IN ('TOTAL','ACCNAME')
        OR (d.name = 'ABCD' AND d.row_num = (
          SELECT MIN(d2.row_num)
          FROM data d2
          WHERE d2.row_num > r_baccstart.baccstart_row_num AND d2.row_num < r_baccstart.baccend_row_num
          AND d2.name = 'ABCD'
        ))
      )
    )
    -- Agg the rows into a single XML block (note: EVALNAME for dynamic XML element name)
    SELECT 
      XMLELEMENT("BACCSTART"
      , XMLAGG(
          XMLELEMENT(EVALNAME(dr.name), dr.value)
          ORDER BY DECODE(dr.name, 'TOTAL', 1, 'ABCD', 2, 3)
        )
      ) xml_data
    INTO l_xml_data
    FROM data_rows dr;

    INSERT INTO data_xml VALUES (l_xml_data);

  END LOOP baccstart_loop;

END;
```

I tried to get it do all the work in a single query, but `XMLAGG` performance seems to drop through the floor as soon as you apply a `GROUP BY` with this many rows (something I've seen happen time and time again). Performance became much more acceptable when the `XMLAGG` was limited to as few rows as possible.

The resulting XML gets inserted into a table called `data_xml` (just so I could easily see the results), but you can substitute whatever you need to do with the XML fragments once they're generated!

I'd advise if you are inserting the data into a table, then simply do an `INSERT`/`SELECT` as opposed to `SELECT INTO` followed by an `INSERT` as it'll be faster due to the lack of context switching between SQL and PL/SQL.

The following DDL/DML was used to set up this example:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  row_num INTEGER
, name    VARCHAR2(10)
, value   VARCHAR2(10)
)
/

CREATE TABLE data_xml (
  xml_data XMLTYPE
)
/

CREATE SEQUENCE data_seq
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 1000
/

BEGIN

  FOR idx IN 1 .. 500 LOOP

    INSERT INTO data (row_num, name, value) 
    VALUES (data_seq.NEXTVAL, 'DOCSTART', NULL);

    INSERT INTO data (row_num, name, value) 
    VALUES (data_seq.NEXTVAL, 'BACCSTART', NULL);

    INSERT INTO data (row_num, name, value) 
    VALUES (data_seq.NEXTVAL, 'ABCD', 'abcd');

    INSERT INTO data (row_num, name, value) 
    VALUES (data_seq.NEXTVAL, 'ABCD', 'abcd2');

    INSERT INTO data (row_num, name, value) 
    VALUES (data_seq.NEXTVAL, 'PQRS', 'pqrs');

    INSERT INTO data (row_num, name, value) 
    VALUES (data_seq.NEXTVAL, 'PQRS', 'pqrs2');

    INSERT INTO data (row_num, name, value) 
    VALUES (data_seq.NEXTVAL, 'TOTAL', '100');

    INSERT INTO data (row_num, name, value) 
    VALUES (data_seq.NEXTVAL, 'ACCNAME', 'name');

    INSERT INTO data (row_num, name, value) 
    VALUES (data_seq.NEXTVAL, 'BACCEND', NULL);

    INSERT INTO data (row_num, name, value) 
    VALUES (data_seq.NEXTVAL, 'BACCSTART', NULL);

    INSERT INTO data (row_num, name, value) 
    VALUES (data_seq.NEXTVAL, 'ABCD', 'abcd');

    INSERT INTO data (row_num, name, value) 
    VALUES (data_seq.NEXTVAL, 'ABCD', 'abcd2');

    INSERT INTO data (row_num, name, value) 
    VALUES (data_seq.NEXTVAL, 'PQRS', 'pqrs3');

    INSERT INTO data (row_num, name, value) 
    VALUES (data_seq.NEXTVAL, 'PQRS', 'pqrs4');

    INSERT INTO data (row_num, name, value) 
    VALUES (data_seq.NEXTVAL, 'TOTAL', '150');

    INSERT INTO data (row_num, name, value) 
    VALUES (data_seq.NEXTVAL, 'ACCNAME', 'name');

    INSERT INTO data (row_num, name, value) 
    VALUES (data_seq.NEXTVAL, 'BACCEND', NULL);

    INSERT INTO data (row_num, name, value) 
    VALUES (data_seq.NEXTVAL, 'DOCEND', NULL);

  END LOOP;

END;
/
```

Comment: Hi Ben, your post have been very useful for my requirement. Need another help regarding this. For say 200 such repeatable blocks, for ACCNAME I have to fetch a value which will be populated in the output xml. For example <BACCSTART><TOTAL>100</TOTAL><ABCD>abcd</ABCD><ABCD>abcd2</ABCD><ACCNAME>name</ACCNAME></BACCSTART>

Comment: Hi Ben, another point to mention here, I need any one of <ABCD> per block, but this time I noticed that I am getting all ABCD values in the xml for a particular block.

Comment: I've updated the answer to arbitrarily take the first ABCD per block.